# ¿Cómo anteponer una condicion "if" antes de un evento OnClientClick de un botón?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Necesito hacer algo así en el evento `OnClientClick` pero obviamente esta sintaxis está mal, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Insertar" OnClientClick=if(GridView2.Rows.Count > 0){"return confirm('¿Esta seguro de enviar los datos que ingresó?')"} runat="server" Text="Ingresar" OnClick="btn_Insertar_Click" BackColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Yellow" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
```

Comment: Si te sirve una solucion JS, tenes 3 hasta ahora. Si estas buscando alguna de otro tipo, por favor aclara tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es detener al cachar el postback:

- Master.js

```js
class ConfirmacionAlerta {

    constructor() {
    }

    static build(title, text, confirmText, cancelText) {
        return swal({
            title: title,
            html: text,
            type: 'question',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: '<span class="fa fa-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + confirmText,
            cancelButtonText: '<span class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + cancelText,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            allowEnterKey: false
        })
    }

}
```

La mandas a llamar desde donde lo ocupes:

```
static Confirm(ctl, event, pregunta, aceptar, cancelar) {
    let defaultaction = $(ctl).prop("href");
    event.preventDefault();
    ConfirmacionAlerta
        .build('CONFIRMAR', pregunta, aceptar, cancelar)
        .then((isconfirm) => {
            if (isconfirm)
                window.location.href = defaultaction;
            return isconfirm;
        })
}
```

En el Button, no necesariamente LinkButton lo llamas de esta manera:

```html
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnPagar" OnClientClick="return PagaPaquete.GenerarToken(this, event)" OnClick="Pagar_Click" Text="Pagar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

En el código del botón solo llama a una función de JavaScript:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Insertar" OnClientClick="MiFuncion();" runat="server" Text="Ingresar" OnClick="btn_Insertar_Click" BackColor="Yellow" BorderColor="Yellow" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
```

En JavaScript pon las condiciones que necesitas:

```
function MiFuncion() {
    if(GridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return confirm('¿Esta seguro de enviar los datos que ingresó?')
    } 
}
```

Esta es una de las formas cómo lo puedes hacer, pero ya depende que solución se adecue más a tu necesidad.

Comment: Desde Javascript no puedes acceder directamente al objeto, debe ser algo como `if(document.getElementByID('<%=GridView2.ClientID%>').rows.length)`

Comment: Ok, gracias.. solo era la idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de muchas formas, pero yo lo haría con JS:

Primero le pondia un ID a tu gridview: Gridview2ID

```
<button onclick="mifuncion()">

<script>
    function mifuncion(){
     if(ocument.getElementById('Gridview2ID') > 0)
     //Aqui tu lógica
     confirm('¿Esta seguro de enviar los datos que ingresó?');
    }
</script>
```